# KML Linestring plotting problems

Tags: xml, xslt, kml, google-earth

I currently have an XML file with some coordinates.
This XML is transformed throw an XSLT file into a KML file (only with placemarks). I've tested it on Google Earth and it's working fine.
Now, I'm trying to use the same coordinates I use for the placemarks, in order to plot a linestring which connects the placemarks, however, this linestring is not being correctly plotted, as you can see in the image below. As you can see, it seems that my linestring is going back and forward.
Any idea of what this might be?

[image: LineString]

The XSLT code I'm using for creating the linestring is the following

```
<Style id="rangecolour">
            <LineStyle><color>660000FF</color><width>1</width></LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle><color>660000FF</color></PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="linecolour">
            <LineStyle><color>660000FF</color><width>3</width></LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <name>distribution/range</name>
            <description></description>
            <styleUrl>#linecolour</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>
                    <xsl:for-each select="xs:experience/xs:data/xs:provider">
                        <xsl:value-of select="xs:longitude"/>,<xsl:value-of select="xs:latitude"/>,<xsl:value-of select="xs:altitude"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>
```

And the resulting KML part for the linestring is the following one:

```
    <Style id="rangecolour">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>660000FF</color>
    <width>1</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>660000FF</color>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="linecolour">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>660000FF</color>
    <width>3</width>
  </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
  <name>distribution/range</name>
  <description/>
  <styleUrl>#linecolour</styleUrl>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>-9.275993,38.757603,210.2
    -9.276027,38.757572,228.1
    ...
    -9.257803,38.75908,159.5
    -9.256753,38.75883,159.5
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

Many thanks for any usefull help.

Answer (score 0):

The LineString is drawn in order of the coordinates provided, so you probably need to re-order your coordinates so that the LineString is drawn how you'd like.

Without seeing your actual coordinates in your KML, this would be my guess.

Comment: Here are the coordinates:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rqAm2ehTqzCt-dhlCC46BnNwQyRv-RaWoqQIzThp20o/edit?usp=sharing

Note that if you visualize it on Google Maps, latitude and longitude must be switched (the first two values of each line) and the altitude (the third one) ignored.
But if you try it on Google Earth or this website (http://display-kml.appspot.com/), it should work as it is.
Thank you :)